# Sum the maximum values based on criteria Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, sumifs

The objective is to calculate the total allowance for the kids in my data set that are aged 12+. In this example using the data set below, the outcome should be 9 (5+2+2). Can someone please help me with a formula? Thanks!

```
ID      Age   Allowance
Fred    12    6
Fred    15    10
Fred    18    5
Joe     12    2
Sam     12    2
DJ      10    1
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Olivebel. There are several ways this could be done.  You might try SUMIF().

Comment: I believe OP included the `sumif` tag. Olivebel, did you already try using a SUMIF()? If so, it might be helpful to include your attempt in your question, and tell us how it didn't work :)

Answer (score 1):

With Office 365 Excel:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,A2:A7,B:B,">=12",B:B,MAXIFS(B:B,A:A,A2:A7))/COUNTIFS(A:A,A2:A7))
```

[image]

---

If one does not have Office 365 Excel then one can use a helper column and sum that.

In D2 Put:

```
=IF(AND(B2=AGGREGATE(14,7,$B$2:$B$7/($A$2:$A$7=A2),1),B2>=12),C2,"")
```

And copy down.  Then sum at the bottom.

[image]